# Knockout bindings breaking in foreach binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a foreach binding that looks like:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="template: { name: 'tablsUlTemplate', foreach: Operators }">
    <li class="active"><a href="#summary" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#permitting" data-toggle="tab">Permitting</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/html" id="tablsUlTemplate">
    <li><a data-bind="attr: { href: NameHash }" data-toggle="tab"><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></a></li>
</script>
```

The reason for this is there is two tabs that will always be there and I add other tabs depending if it has been added or not.

The problem is not with the above but with the tab content, that part looks similar to the above it is just a lot so decided to show 1 complete part at lease.

I then have (the broken part)

```
<div class="tab-content" data-bind="template: { name: 'tablsContentTemplate', foreach: Operators }" >
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="summary">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="permitting">
        <table class="span10">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Submission
                    </th>
                    <th>Approval
                    </th>
                    <th>Timeline
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-bind="visible: PermittingCAAActive">
                    <td>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            CAA
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                            <input id="text12" type="text" readonly="true" class="spandate" runat="server" data-bind="value: PermittingCAASubmission" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                            <input id="text13" type="text" readonly="true" class="spandate" runat="server" data-bind="value: PermittingCAAApproval" />
                         </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                            <input id="text14" type="text" readonly="true" class="spandate" runat="server" data-bind="value: PermittingCAATimeline" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

My issue is that the bindings within the bindings of the foreach is not working.

Please note the VM:

```
viewModel = {
    Operators: ko.observableArray(),
    PermittingCAAActive : ko.observable(),
    PermittingCAAApproval : ko.observable(),
    PermittingCAASubmission: ko.observable(),
    PermittingCAATimeline: ko.observable(),
}
```

Please note I omitted stuff that was not relevant to the problem.

Comment: What about it is "not working?" What actually happens? What are you expecting to happen? Do you ever set `Operators`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to not mix fixed content with templated content, possibly using virtual elements, as shown here below:

```
<ul>
    <li data-bind="text: PermittingCAAActive"></li>
    <!-- ko template: {name: 'tablsUlTemplate', foreach: Operators} -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>

<script type="text/html" id="tablsUlTemplate">
    <li><a data-bind="attr: { href: NameHash }" data-toggle="tab"><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></a></li>
</script>
```

This will make bindings easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks was exactly what I needed, didn't know about the virtual bindings

Answer (score 1):

```
//  data-bind="template: { name: 'tablsContentTemplate', foreach: Operators }"

<td>
     <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
        <input id="text12" type="text" readonly="true" class="spandate" runat="server" data-bind="value: PermittingCAASubmission" />
     </div>
</td>
```

Lets examine above binding , after using foreach your value bindings expect to find **PermittingCAASubmission** inside one of the operators. But there is no PermittingCAASubmission inside it so adding $parent or $root can  resolve your issue.

```
 data-bind="value: $parent.PermittingCAASubmission"
```

Please include your error message to your question , we can say more about after that.